Flutter MIFARE Desfire EV1 card getting a length error while trying to get session key
I am rather new to NFC communication. The following code produces a length error when sending a cryptographic response. I am wondering if I am getting the step order wrong here. The Desfire NFC card is new and the encryption key should all be zero from what I've heard.
Now, I would be very grateful if somebody with Mifare EV1 experience might be able to point me in thee right direction here. I feel a bit blind.
Future<void> _authenticateDesfire() async {
    try {
      // Stage: Initiate authentication
      print("Stage: Initiating authentication...");

      Uint8List authCommand = Uint8List.fromList([0x90, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00]);
      print("Stage: Sending APDU for authentication: ${authCommand.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      var response = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(authCommand);
      print("Stage: Received response from authentication APDU: $response");

      // Check if we received the correct length error response
      if (response.length == 2 && response[0] == 0x91 && response[1] == 0x7E) {
        print("Stage: Initiate authentication: Length error detected in the response. The command length might be incorrect.");
        return;
      }

      // Stage: Process received challenge
      String receivedChallenge = response.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ');
      print("Stage: Processing received challenge: $receivedChallenge");

      // Extract the challenge (excluding the last byte if necessary)
      List<int> challenge = response.sublist(0, response.length - 1);
      print("Extracted challenge: ${challenge.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      // Triple DES encryption key (24 bytes of 0)
      List<List<int>> tripleDesKey = [
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
      ];

      // Stage: Calculate the response to the challenge using Triple DES
      print("Stage: Calculating response using Triple DES...");
      List<int> calculatedResponse = DES.tripleDESEncrypt(challenge, tripleDesKey);
      print("Calculated response before appending: ${calculatedResponse.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      // Append 8 additional bytes to the calculated response
      List<int> extendedResponse = List<int>.from(calculatedResponse)..addAll([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);
      print("Calculated response after appending: ${extendedResponse.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      // Rotate the bytes to the left
      List<int> rotatedResponse = extendedResponse.sublist(1)..add(extendedResponse[0]);
      Uint8List finalResponse = Uint8List.fromList(rotatedResponse);
      print("Rotated response: ${finalResponse.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      // Stage: Sending cryptographic response
      Uint8List responseCommand = Uint8List.fromList([0x90, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00, finalResponse.length, ...finalResponse, 0x00]);
      print("Stage: Sending calculated response: ${responseCommand.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}");

      var finalTagResponse = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(responseCommand);
      print("Stage: Received final response: $finalTagResponse");

      // Check for errors in the final response
      if (finalTagResponse.length == 2 && finalTagResponse[0] == 0x91 && finalTagResponse[1] == 0x7E) {
        print("Stage: Sending cryptographic response: Length error detected in the response. The command length might be incorrect.");
        return;
      }

      // Stage: Process final response
      finalTagResponse.forEach((byte) {
        print("Stage: Processing final response byte: 0x${byte.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase().padLeft(2, '0')}");
      });

      // Finish NFC session
      print("Stage: Finishing NFC session...");
      await FlutterNfcKit.finish();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Stage: Error during authentication: $e");
    }
  }


Here is the relevant output:
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Starting NFC polling...
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Tag detected. Tag ID: 0489650A0E6E80
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Processing detected tag...
I/flutter (23065): Stage: ISO 7816 Tag detected.
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Initiating authentication...
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Sending APDU for authentication: 90 0a 00 00 01 00 00
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Received response from authentication APDU: [175, 97, 253, 196, 18, 48, 214, 29, 145, 175]
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Processing received challenge: af 61 fd c4 12 30 d6 1d 91 af
I/flutter (23065): Extracted challenge: af 61 fd c4 12 30 d6 1d 91
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Calculating response using Triple DES...
I/flutter (23065): Calculated response before appending: 93 ce 46 1c d1 7f d4 0f c9 cf af ac 30 8b c9 8d
I/flutter (23065): Calculated response after appending: 93 ce 46 1c d1 7f d4 0f c9 cf af ac 30 8b c9 8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
I/flutter (23065): Rotated response: ce 46 1c d1 7f d4 0f c9 cf af ac 30 8b c9 8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 93
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Sending calculated response: 90 af 00 00 18 ce 46 1c d1 7f d4 0f c9 cf af ac 30 8b c9 8d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 93 00
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Received final response: [145, 126]
I/flutter (23065): Stage: Sending cryptographic response: Length error detected in the response. The command length might be incorrect.


Why are you "Append 8 additional bytes to the calculated response" ? Your "calculated response" should be of length 22 and not of 30 bytes. Btw: As we are working usually on hex based values please convert the data (e.g. response [145, 126]), thanks.
